# Add options as tags from a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, tags

I am trying to implement a list that gives suggestions to users as they type in a form field and add that option as a tag once they click/enter on the option. just like in Upwork skills field[image]

I have languages as options and users can select multiple languages.
Right now, I have it implemented as a dropdown with checkboxes.

```
<div class="button-group">
 <label class="form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose Languages<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span> </label>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li>
    <a class="small"><%= f.check_box :language5, {}, 'none', nil %> No Other Language</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="small"><%= f.check_box :language1, {}, 'arabic', nil %> Arabic </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="small"><%= f.check_box :language2, {}, 'cantonese', nil %> Cantonese </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="small"><%= f.check_box :language3, {}, 'french', nil  %> French </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="small"><%= f.check_box :language4, {}, 'spanish', nil %> Spanish </a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Would love some guidance in the implementation of the tag-type method. TIA.

Comment: Try select2 for it. Here is the gem - https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails

Comment: not sure this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Then I think you need to explain more detailed what are you looking for

Comment: I need a form field for languages that adds every language that the user types in, as a tag. Exactly like the upwork screenshot shared above. And exactly like when adding tags with Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: select2 can do it all, moreover, it can add new tags to db on the fly

Comment: Check the last example here: https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Comment: @Pablo thank you, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Vasilisa sorry I didn't dive deeper in my google search on select2. You were right.

Comment: @A.A.F, happy to help :)

Comment: Can't seem to figure out how to run select2-rails. getting multiple errors. Followed multiple tutorials to load jquery and the gem properly without success. 
1. JQuery is not defined
2. Select2 is not a function.